# Example of polymorphism in buit in library of C++?

Tags: c++, stl

Just wondering what's the example of polymorphism in STL C++ Library?

Comment: Locale facets and stream buffers. And polymorphic memory resources.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or give me link?

Comment: Do you mean the `C++ Standard Library` as a whole? Because that's not the same thing as the `STL` which only properly refers to the *containers* and *algorithms* parts of the library

Comment: No I didn't mean that. Kerrek and Karl are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one that comes to mind is the [`iostream` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

At the bottom of the heirarchy, there is the `ios_base` class, then the `basic_ios` class that provide some very primitive state retrieval functions and formatting flags.

From there, the library kind of divides into two, providing `basic_istream` and `basic_ostream` classes (with the exception of basic_iostream, which inherits both of these), each of which provide various specific methods for interacting with the stream (such as the `<<` and `>>` operators).

If you want an actual, concrete example of polymorphism in this library, take a look at `std::cin` and `std:cout` and `std::cerr`, which are implemented as global objects, but only exposed as `basic_istream` and `basic_ostream` objects respectively.